# Minify ES6 and generate source-maps with Browserify

Tags: optimization, browserify, source-maps

I use **browserify** and **6to5ify** to compile ES6 to JS and assemble project.
The problem is that I can't find any solution, how to minify compiled javascript, and generate source-maps for minified js.

My build task code is:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'), 
source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
browserify = require('browserify'),
buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
buildErrorHandler = require('./../utilities/build-error-handler').handleBuildError
;

gulp.task('js:build-scripts', function() {
  var commandLineParameters = process.argv.slice(2);
  var releaseModeRequired = commandLineParameters.indexOf('--release') > -1;

  var bundler = browserify({
    debug: true,
    entries: ['./src/js/entry-point.js']
  })
  ;

  var pipeLine =  bundler 
  .transform('6to5ify')
  .bundle()
  .on('error', buildErrorHandler)
  .pipe(plumber({
    errorHandler: buildErrorHandler
  }))
  .pipe(source('application.js'));

  if(releaseModeRequired){
    pipeLine = pipeLine.pipe(buffer()) 
    .pipe(uglify());
  }

  pipeLine =pipeLine.pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
  ;

  return pipeLine;
});
```

If I don't minify code, sourcemaps are working fine, but if I uglify it, sourcemaps disappear.

I tried several solutions like [this](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md) or [this](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify) but none of them works.

EDITED:

```
"browserify": "^8.1.3",
"gulp": "^3.8.10",
```

Comment: What versions of browserify and gulp-uglify? You'll also need to integrate gulp-sourcemaps into your pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been an issue with Browserify + Uglify.js for a long time. [It got fixed in this commit](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/commit/ad18689d926d25c7a25b95c630c2ad05b7b5f5b5), <del>but has not been released yet</del> and was release with `v2.4.21`.

Comment: Looks like this was released with version 2.4.21.